# ContourPlot plots an empty graph

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I want to display the solution of the equation
$$e^{2ix} = (x+i\sqrt{1-x^2}) e^{-iy},$$
where $-1\leq x \leq 1$ and $0\leq y\leq 2\pi$. I used the `ContourPlot` as follows:

```
ContourPlot[
 Exp[2 I x] == (x + I Sqrt[1 - x^2])^2 Exp[-I y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 
  2 Pi}]
```

However, it plots an empty graph! How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It should be noticed that `ComplexContourPlot[
 Exp[2 I Re[
     z]] == (Re[z] + I Sqrt[1 - Re[z]^2])^2 Exp[-I Im[z]], {z, -1 + 
   0 I, 1 + 2 \[Pi] I}, PlotPoints -> 200]` also produces an empty plot. Is this a bug?

Comment: `ContourPlot[{Re[Exp[2 I x] - (x + I Sqrt[1 - x^2])^2 Exp[-I y]] == 0,    Im[Exp[2 I x] - (x + I Sqrt[1 - x^2])^2 Exp[-I y]] == 0}, {x, -1,    1}, {y, 0, 2 Pi},   ContourStyle -> {{Thickness[.02], Opacity[.5],      Red}, {Thickness[.005], Black}}, PlotPoints -> 100]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns empty graph because the given contour/expression requires infinite precision to be drawn properly due to complex terms. When you try to plot that contour as given, there always will be some tiny imaginary term, which cannot be used in plotting.

You could think of drawing `Re[f[x,y]]==0` and `Im[f[x,y]]==0`

```
f[x_, y_] := Exp[2*I*x] - (x + I*Sqrt[1 - x^2])^2*Exp[-I*y]
GraphicsRow[
 ContourPlot[{#}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 100] &
 /@ {Re[f[x, y]] == 0, Im[f[x, y]] == 0}
]
```

[image]

and trying to draw their intersection using

```
ConditionalExpression[Re[f[x, y]], Im[f[x, y]]==0] == 0
```

But this contour recurs another precision problem when plotting and returns empty graph. A workaround to this is introducing small `r` such that `-r < Im[f[x,y]] < r`:

```
r = 0.01;
ContourPlot[
 ConditionalExpression[Re[f[x, y]], -r < Im[f[x, y]] < r] == 0
, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: Why does `ComplexContourPlot[  Exp[2 I Re[      z]] == (Re[z] + I Sqrt[1 - Re[z]^2])^2 Exp[-I Im[z]], {z, -1 +     0 I, 1 + 2 \[Pi] I}, PlotPoints -> 200]` also produce an empty plot? Is this a bug?