# Strange Problem in ListSliceContourPlot3D, missing parts in final results

Tags: plotting

I have strange missing parts in contour plot of values using following code:

```
points = SpherePoints[100];
values = RandomReal[{0.000015831726713187197, 
    0.000017509814943585526}, 100];
data = MapThread[Append, {points, values}];
ListSliceContourPlot3D[data, "CenterSphere", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

As you can see there are many missing parts (holes) in plot:

[image]

,Would you please help.

Comment: You get holes because you have not enough points.

Comment: actually I tried it with 1000 points, the same problem appeared!

Comment: You are right. I would report it to: support@wolfram.com

Answer (score 1):

This is a similar problem to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263473/). A workaround is to set a looser region:

```
ListSliceContourPlot3D[data
, ImplicitRegion[1 - 0.2 < x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 1 + 0.2, {x, y, z}]
, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I am afraid "the sphere radius" interferes in the resulted contours, the result of ListSliceContourPlot3D. How I can be sure that radius is exactly equals to 1?